# A break is added when styling my DIV tags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, styling

I need to style a simple div, that I am using in a InfoWindow on a costum google maps. I am doing in step by step, the strings are read in via a database, so is the small picture URL.

Everything is loaded in fine, but I can't get the styling of the div tag correct. On the screenshot you can see that a break is added after the first plus ("+") that I use to make up the string in the right div next to the picture.

Here you can see the screenshot of what is going wrong:
[image: capture]

Any body knows what I am doing wrong? This is the piece of code I use:

```
var ARP = 'ARP: ' + markers[i].getAttribute("ARP").toString();
var Place = '<br>Place: ' + markers[i].getAttribute("Place").toString();
var Fuel = '<br>Fuel type: ' + markers[i].getAttribute("Fuel").toString();
var Cap = '<br>Capaciteit: ' + markers[i].getAttribute("Cap").toString() + ' MW';
var icon_image = {
url: markers[i].getAttribute("Icon_url").toString(),
};


var image = '<div id="foto" style="float:left;width:150px;padding-right:10px;background-color:#EEEEEE"><img src="'+ markers[i].getAttribute("Image_url") + '" alt=""  ></div>';

var temp_tekst = ARP + Place  +  Fuel + Cap ;
temp_tekst = temp_tekst.toString();
var tekst = '<div id="tekst" style="width:200px;height=150px;background-   color:#FFA500">'+ temp_tekst +'</div>';

var content = '<div id="container" style="width:500px;height=150px;" > ' + image + tekst + '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the call `markers[i].getAttribute("ARP").toString()` is returning a string with either a `<br>` tag or a `<div>` or other block-level element. Try either stripping out HTML tags from this string or using the web browser inspector to ensure there are no html tags in the string you get back.

Another possibility is that if you have a fixed width on the container with the orange background, the browser will automatically wrap to accomodate the fixed size.

Comment: Your second possibility is correct, the fixed with inside the second div was indeed the problem, thank you!